# Derived version of projection formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, derived-functors

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a continuous map of locally compact spaces. Denote by $Sh(X)$, $Sh(Y)$ the categories of sheaves of $k$-vector spaces for some field $k$ and by $D^b(X)$, $D^b(Y)$ their bounded derived categories. Suppose that $f_!$ has a finite cohomological dimension so that the right adjoint $f^! \colon D^b(Y) \to D^b (X)$ to $\mathbf Rf_!$ exists. I want to show that there is a natural isomorphism
$$
   \mathbf Rf_!(f^{-1} F \otimes G) \cong F \otimes \mathbf Rf_! G, \quad F \in D^b(Y), \; G \in D^b(X).
$$
This isomorphism was used, e.g. in the proof of Theorem 7 (Verdier duality), p. 11 of [these](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.polytechnique.fr%2Fperso%2Fmassot.patrick%2FgdtSS%2FamielRHom.pdf&ei=Pt7gVNXaEcaI7AaNjIGIAg&usg=AFQjCNHB1pw0lneQohL97qN20wBOgbDPFA&sig2=A60MM9O9jjoDzyKhytomyw&bvm=bv.85970519,d.ZWU) notes.

I was trying to take an arbitrary $H \in D^b(Y)$ and write
$$
   \mathrm{Hom}_{D^b(Y)} (\mathbf Rf_!(f^{-1} F \otimes G),H) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D^b(X)}(f^{-1}F \otimes G,f^! H) \\
   \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D^b(X)} (G, \mathbf R\mathcal{Hom}(f^{-1} F,f^! H))
$$
Now, if I could use that $\mathbf R\mathcal{Hom}(f^{-1} F, f^! H) \cong f^! \mathbf R \mathcal{Hom}(F,H)$ then I could continue the above sequence of isomorphisms as
$$
   \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D^b(X)} (G, f^! \mathbf R\mathcal{Hom}(F,H)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D^b(Y)} (\mathbf Rf_! G, \mathbf R\mathcal{Hom}(F,H)) \\
   \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{D^b(Y)}(F \otimes \mathbf Rf_! G, H).
$$
By Yoneda this implies the required statement. But now I have to prove that $\mathbf R\mathcal{Hom}(f^{-1} F, f^! H) \cong f^! \mathbf R \mathcal{Hom}(F,H)$. I'm not sure that it is easier than the original statement. Please, help me.

Comment: The last formula you want to prove is just another form of projection formula. Assuming the adjunctions, there are three equivalent forms of projection formula, which are related by Yoneda (same as your argument). The third one is the upgrade of adjunctions $f_! \dashv f^!$ to the internal Hom. I wonder if one can directly obtain derived version of projection formula from the non-derived one.